# How do I extract all keys from this JSON file?

Tags: python, json

The data I'm working with is the entire list of yugioh cards, found at this endpoint: https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php

There's a top-level `data` node that I can ignore, but each sub-node immediately after that (`0`, `1`, `2`,...) is a unique card in the cardset. I want to find out how many unique keys there are in this entire dataset. The tricky part is that each card could have different sub-nodes than another card. Eventually I want to put this all into SQL tables, but for now I need to know all of the keys. Some examples of the keys are `id`, `name`, `archetype`, `atk`, `def`, and `card_sets`. How do I extract a unique list of all keys? I'm looking for the easiest way to get this list. I have experience in Python and T-SQL, but any other language is fine since my goal is to just look at the list.

Comment: You mean, you want to know every string that is used as a key anywhere in the structure, at any level of the structure? Do you know how to do a depth-first search of such a structure? Do you know how to accumulate the keys as you find them, removing duplicates as you find them (hint: use a data structure that automatically rejects duplicates, e.g. `set` in Python)? If you put those two things together, do you see how that solves the problem?

Comment: Asking us about data in a link that leads to 13MB and 562,971 lines of data is not really providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There's also no guarantee that data will be around for future readers. Consider making a subset  of the data that's small enough to put in the body of the question that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Also: do not write questions asking for help in "any language", or tag the question with multiple languages unless you **must** have code written in **each** language tagged in order to have a valid solution to the problem. If you have a practical problem and have not chosen an implementation language, then you do not have a properly specific and focused question for Stack Overflow. We don't do top-level program design, requirements gathering etc. If you are looking for language-agnostic help with an algorithm, that is a separate kind of question; please tag those `langauge-agnostic` instead.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel how do I do a depth-first search? I can figure out the rest after that.

Comment: Once you have parsed JSON data, you have **just** a data structure of nested dictionaries (objects, mappings, associative arrays, whatever your language calls them) and lists (arrays, vectors, whatever your language calls them), that you then manipulate *the same way* that you would if you had gotten *the same data, by any other method*. Depth-first search is a classic algorithm which you [should](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) try to [research](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=depth+first+search).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used generators to solve this problem
If the data is dict, it's keys will be `yield`
If the data is list or tuple, it's elements continue to be parsed
**String are also iterable and need to be excluded**

```
import json
import requests
from collections import Iterable


def get_key(data):
    if isinstance(data, dict):
        for k, v in data.items():
            yield k
            yield from get_key(v)
    elif isinstance(data, Iterable) and not isinstance(data, str):
        for i in data:
            yield from get_key(i)


def main():
    url = "https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php"
    res = requests.get(url)
    data = json.loads(res.text)["data"]
    result = set(get_key(data))
    print(result)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the output

```
{'set_rarity', 'def', 'image_url_small', 'ban_tcg', 'set_rarity_code', 'linkmarkers', 'type', 'coolstuffinc_price', 'cardmarket_price', 'id', 'image_url', 'level', 'name', 'set_code', 'banlist_info', 'desc', 'set_name', 'card_prices', 'attribute', 'linkval', 'ebay_price', 'tcgplayer_price', 'card_sets', 'atk', 'set_price', 'ban_ocg', 'ban_goat', 'archetype', 'amazon_price', 'scale', 'race', 'card_images'}
```

Comment: `Warning (from warnings module):`
from the -   `line 1: `
DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working